# Python Pandas replace() not working

Tags: pandas

I have some fields that have some junk in them from an upstream process. I'm  trying to delete **'\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object'** from a column that has this junk appended to an email address.

```
report_df['Owner'].replace('\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object',inplace=True)
report_df['Owner'][26]
```

Output:

```
'   Jane.Doe@company.com\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object'
```

I've also tried the following variants w/o success:

```
replace('Name: hwowneremail, dtype: object', inplace=True)

replace('\\r\\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object', inplace=True

replace(r'\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object', inplace=True)

replace('\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object', "", inplace=True)

replace(to_value='\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object', value=' ',inplace=True)

replace('\\r\\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember, Python Pandas was changed a little bit in replace. You should try passing over a regex keyword argument.

Like so;

```
report_df['Owner'].replace({'\r\nName: hwowneremail, dtype: object':''},regex=True)
```

Comment: That did it! Interestingly I started with that, but didn't have regex=True. I added inplace=True and problem solved. Thank You!

Comment: This stumped me for a while as well. `regex=True` is now required, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use:

```
report_df.Owner.str.replace(r'\r\n.*', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or sometimes just make sure there is no white space before or after the character/str you are looking for(expl. ? ):

```
df.replace(r'\s*\?\s*', np.nan, regex=True)
```

or just make sure you specify you are looking for a string:

```
df.replace(r'\?', np.nan, regex=True)
```

and for both cases: and don`t forget

```
regex=True
```